# Дремучий и дремота

Tags: однокоренные-слова

О непроходимом густом лесе говорят, что он дремучий. Но какое отношение это слово имеет в слову "дремота" (а корень у них явно один)?

Answer (score 3):

Этимологический русскоязычный словарь Фасмера :

> **ДРЕМУЧИЙ** 
>  (напр., лес), т. е. "дремлющий, спящий", ср. *непробудный лес* (Гоголь).

Этимологический словарь Крылова чуть более подробен :

> ДРЕМУЧИЙ 
>  Это определение леса (впрочем, иногда так определяют и невежественного человека) связано с глаголом дремать. Дремучий означало "дремлющий", то есть "глухой, непроходимый, не тревожимый в своем сне". Любопытно, что прежде можно было встретить и такое определение к слову лес: беспробудный.

От себя добавлю, что в дремучем лесу очень темно, даже днем солнечные лучи с большим трудом пробиваются сквозь густые ветви деревьев.

Comment: А ночью там вообще такая кромешная темнота, что без разницы: закрыты глаза или открыты!

Comment: Дремучий  лес  -  еловый,  а  сосновый  уже  не  дремучий.  А  еловый   как-то  давит.